# Resizing thumbnails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know what I can use to resize all images to the same width (and proportional height) within Rails?

Comment: This sort of question is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442248/basic-image-resizing-in-ruby-on-rails.