# Is there any option to reduce a image file size in ROR?

Tags: ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application i am getting images from an API,which are bigger in size like 80kb. I want to reduce this image file size to 20kb. Is there any way to do this using ROR?

Comment: Are you storing the image? Or just pass it through to end user.  What are you doing now?

Comment: I am just displaying the image to end user..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to resize the image to whatever size you like if you're storing the image somewhere in your application and not just reading it.

Something like this:

```
has_attached_file :image,
  :styles => {
    :small => "100x" },
  :convert_options => {
    :small => "-quality 75 -strip" }
```

It can reduce the size significantly according to their [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation).

Comment: I am not storing the image anywhere in the application. I am just getting the image from API and displaying it to the end user.

Comment: How do you expect to change the size of the file if you do nothing to it?

Comment: I have the image url. is there any way to change while displaying it?

Comment: No. The browser will load that image directly from the url. Your app is not even involved. Therefore there is no way for you to minify that image.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442497/1496501

TL;DR - Use [RMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/), it's wonderful.

In your case the [minify method](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#minify) will be useful